# Create SQL column that subtracts two date columns

Tags: sql

This is how my columns look.

I want to create a column that contains the differences between the start time and end time columns.

```
Start_Time 
2019-02-01 22:38:54.0000000
2019-02-01 22:39:18.0000000
2019-02-01 22:44:43.0000000
2019-02-04 22:17:41.0000000
2019-02-04 22:18:09.0000000
```

```
End_Time
2019-02-01 22:38:57.0000000
2019-02-01 22:39:28.0000000
2019-02-01 22:44:44.0000000
2019-02-04 22:17:48.0000000
2019-02-04 22:18:21.0000000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please indicate which SQL implementation you're using and edit your post to include that as a tag. It will help us solve your problem.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: How do you want to represent the interval ? As a number of seconds ? An `INTERVAL` data type (if supported by your RDBMS) ? Something else ?

Comment: `select end_time - start_time from the_table`?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to add **computed/generated column** on table

```
CREATE TABLE TBL
( 
    ...
    StartTime datetime,
    EndTime datetime,
    computedColName as DATEDIFF(Endtime,StartTime)
)
```

Table alteration

```
ALTER TABLE TBL
  ADD COLUMN computedColName as DATEDIFF(Endtime, StartTime)
```

Comment: wouldn't there be a subtract sign '-'  instead of comma?

Comment: yes, I was thinking on DATEDIFF then I forgot to add :)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

> DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
>
> TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2)

Description:

DATEDIFF() returns (expr1 – expr2) expressed as a value in days from one date to the other.  expr1 and  expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

TIMEDIFF() returns (expr1 − expr2) expressed as a time value. expr1 and expr2 are time or date-and-time expressions, but both must be of the same type.

> SELECT DATEDIFF( Start_Time, End_Time ) AS DateDiff from table_name

Source: MariaDB [DATEDIFF](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/datediff/) only takes two arguments. It changes according to the MySQL Implementation.